# Dart Flutter get IconData actual icon name by using the code

Tags: dart, flutter-layout

I can use this line of code example to get an icon of MaterialIcons in **icons.dart** by using the `codePoint`

e.g.

```dart
codePoint=0xe146;
Icon(IconData(codePoint, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'));
```

What i would like to get is the actual descriptive name of the icon. Any ideas how I can go about this?

The file where the icons are encoded is **icons.dart** and looks like this for each icon:

```dart
  /// <i class="material-icons md-36">add_box</i> &#x2014; material icon named "add box".
  static const IconData add_box = IconData(0xe146, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');
```

Comment: I'm confused what actually are you asking? you could just use the code  like creating the instance of class that contain this `static const IconData add_box = IconData(0xe146, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');` and invoke it with `instance.add_box` to get the icon. no need to use the codepoint like in first code block

Answer (score 1):

This link shows the descriptive names of the MaterialIcons

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html

Example from the above link:

[image: Screenshot from Flutter documentation]

But actually, the easiest way to use Flutter icons is the following:

```dart
Icon(Icons.ac_unit) // Icons.ac_unit = IconData(0xe037, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hacky solution, but works perfect to me**

Actually I had the same problem and didn't find such a relevant solution. I had the IconData codepoints and the same as you, I needed to get the names from Icons class.

My solution:
I went to Icons class, copied that into multiline string, then I extracted the data into map and woila.

```
    var iconsInString = '''
  /// <i class="material-icons md-36">add_box</i> &#x2014; material icon named "add box".
  static const IconData add_box = IconData(0xe146, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');
''';
    var a = iconsInString.split('\n')
      ..removeWhere((e) => e == '')                       // deleting empty rows
      ..removeWhere((e) => e.substring(0,5) == '  ///');  // deleting comment rows

// extracting names into iterable
    var text = a.map((e) => e.replaceRange(0, 24, '')).map((e) => e.split(' ').first);
// extracting codes into iterable                        
    var cislo = a.map((e) => e.replaceRange(0, 24, '')).map((e) => e.split('IconData(').second.substring(0,6).toInt);
// getting map from iterables
    final icoMapTmp = Map.fromIterables(cislo, text.map((e) => '\'$e\''));
```

then I copied icoMap to clipboard using

```
 Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: icoMapTmp.toString()));
```

and then I just created new file with new map by ctrl+V with the new data like this:

```
const icoMAP = {
  57344: 'ten_k',
  59136: 'ten_k_sharp',
  62687: 'ten_k_rounded',
  60914: 'ten_k_outlined',
  57345: 'ten_mp',
  59137: 'ten_mp_sharp',
  62688: 'ten_mp_rounded',
  60915: 'ten_mp_outlined',
  57346: 'eleven_mp',
  59138: 'eleven_mp_sharp',
  62689: 'eleven_mp_rounded',
  60916: 'eleven_mp_outlined',
  61515: 'zoom_in_map_sharp',
  61500: 'zoom_in_map_rounded',
  58176: 'onetwothree_rounded',
  61531: 'file_download_outlined',
  57347: 'twelve_mp',
  59139: 'twelve_mp_sharp',
  62690: 'twelve_mp_rounded',
  60917: 'twelve_mp_outlined',
  57348: 'thirteen_mp',
  59140: 'thirteen_mp_sharp',
// etc...  sorry the map is huge (6394 lines)
};
```